# How to connect two provider hosted apps sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

How can i connect two provider hosted apps ?.

Comment: what is attempt from your side for solving your problem

Comment: I have no idea on that. Am thinking deploy the two apps into sharepoint page as app parts and connect it.